# Scoping Issue, raw_input variable won't reset

Tags: python

I don't know how to change the code so the deposit variable will reset when the script is running, because if I enter pennies first, the deposit variable will store that for every time the function is called and therefore pressing a different coin like nickels it will not execute its "elif" statement and instead go to the pennies. How do I solve this?

```
pennies_total = 0
nickels_total = 0
dimes_toal = 0
quarters_total = 0
keeprunning = True


def deposit():
    global pennies_total
    global nickels_total
    global dimes_total
    global quarters_total
    deposit = (raw_input("What would you like to deposit? (P for pennies, N for nickels, D for dimes, Q for quarters): ")).upper()
    if deposit == 'P' or 'PENNIES':
        pennies_instance = raw_input("How many pennies would you like to deposit?: ")
        pennies_total = int(pennies_instance) + pennies_total
        print "There are %s pennies in your bank"% (pennies_total)

    elif deposit == 'N' or 'NICKELS':    
        nickels_instance = raw_input("How many nickels would you like to deposit?: ")
        # create if non-integer is input for all classes of coins
        nickels_total = int(nickels_instance) + nickels_total
        print "There are %s nickels in your bank"% (nickels_total)

    while keeprunning == True:
        exc = raw_input("Would you like to deposit or withdraw money? (D for deposit, W   for    withdraw, Q for Quit): ").upper()
        if exc == "D" or "DEPOSIT":
            deposit()
```

Comment: please fix your indentation.

Comment: So many globals just ask for a scoping issue. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression:

```
deposit == 'P' or 'PENNIES'
```

doesn't do what you think it does. That expression will *always* be true, regardless of the value of `deposit`. Thus, the pennies branch is always taken, and the nickel branch is never taken.

Try either:

```
deposit == 'P' or deposit == 'PENNIES'
```

or

```
deposit in ('P', 'PENNIES')
```

and similarly for the other `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes:

1) Change the variable name in:

```
deposit = (raw_input("What would you like to deposit? (P for pennies, N for nickels, D for dimes, Q for quarters): ")).upper()
```

to some other name like: denomination

2) Replace:

```
if deposit == 'P' or 'PENNIES':
```

By:

```
if (denomination == 'P') or (denomination == 'PENNIES'):
```

Do this change for "all" if and "elif" conditions.